# Unity jumping issue, character is not jumping at all

Tags: unity-game-engine

(This is 2D project)

My character need to run left and right and jump on ground. It is my first experience with Unity and it latest available version of it, I manage to make my Character run left and right and flip when it is change direction, but it does not jump at all.

**For the Character** I am currently using 2 Box Collider 2Ds and Rigidbody 2D. Character has mass equal 1.

**For the Ground** I am currently using 2 Box Collider 2Ds. Ground is single sprite which is cover bottom part of screen.

Below is the code for jumping and grounded I am currently trying to use.

```
'''
{


public float maxSpeed = 10f;

public float jumpVelocity = 10f;

private bool isGrounded;

private float move = 0f;

private Rigidbody2D rb2d;       //Store a reference to the Rigidbody2D component required to use 2D Physics.

private SpriteRenderer sprt_render;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    isGrounded = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    GetInput();

}

private void GetInput()
{
    move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


    if (transform.position.x > -6.2 && transform.position.x < 5.7)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }
    else
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed * -1, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
    {
          Debug.Log("Jump");
          rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, jumpVelocity);
          isGrounded = false;
          //rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpVelocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}

}

'''
```

As you can see I try to use two different approach in connection with jump realisation using Velocity and using AddForce result is totally the same it is not jumping even first time. I check thought breakpoint it definitely go trough jumping code but nothing happened.

Comment: add debug statements you will find where it doesnt tie up with what you expected

Comment: What happens if you increase jumpForce to something much higher? (And note you have the jumping AddForce line commented out, it shouldn't be, and if it's only commented out here in your question, then you may want to edit it for clarity.)

Comment: Just tried to remove comment from AddForce statement and increase jumpForce up to 100f and then up to 1000f, nothing changed at all.